# Nginx auth off whole folder

Tags: nginx, htaccess

We're trying to setup Klaviyo on our Zandbox/test site with nginx.

But Klaviyo cant get the data from SOAP when i have htpasswd enabled.
It needs to visit www.mytestdomain.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1 to get the data.

How can i disable auth_basic for the whole api folder? i already did this for some php files, but as this is not a specific php file i dont know. The code i use for php files is:

```
location =  /folder/file.php {
  auth_basic off;
  try_files $uri =404;
  expires off;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  proxy_connect_timeout  2600s;
  proxy_send_timeout  2600s;
  proxy_read_timeout  2600s;
  fastcgi_send_timeout 2600s;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 2600s;
  fastcgi_pass zandbox;
  fastcgi_pass_request_headers on;
  fastcgi_keep_conn off;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root${fastcgi_script_name};
  fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE base;
  fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'd want location to look like this (as /api will tend to forward to /index.php/api from what I've seen in access logs, this rule should cover both)

```
location ~* ^/(index.php/)?api {

}
```